# A Class with a generic constrainst while inheriting from another class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm trying determine if it's possible in C# to have a generic class that inherits from another class such as:

```
public class MySubclass<T> : SomeClass
```

But this time, I want to put a constraint on `T` being of some [other] base class like so:

```
public class MySubclass<T> where T : TBaseClass
```

Is it possible to combine these two?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is slightly unclear, but I think you want:

```
public class MySubclass<T> : SomeClass where T : TBaseClass { }
```